# GetOrgChart: maximum allowed primaryColumns

Tags: orgchart

Is there a upper limit to how many **primaryColumns** you can show in OrgChart.
I cant seem to add more than **4**. If you look at the example below, email address is not rendered. Is this correct behavior? Is there a way to overwrite this setting?

```
     $("#people").getOrgChart({         
        primaryColumns: ["name", "title","department", "phone", "email"],
                dataSource:[{"id":1,"parentId":null,"name":"John Doe","positionId":"771","title":"Vice-President","location":"Location","department":"IT-Dallas","phone":"(333)-444-6363","email":"john.doe@domain.com","image":""}]
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w9Ax8/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add more textPoints to the theme you are using. [**See this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9Ax8/19/).

Within the theme object, I added a custom theme object, and within that added additional textPoints:

```
    ...
    textPointsNoImage: [{
            x: 20,
            y: 30,
            width: 330
        }, {
            x: 20,
            y: 50,
            width: 330
        }, {
            x: 20,
            y: 75,
            width: 330
        }, {
            x: 20,
            y: 95,
            width: 330
        }, {
            x: 20,
            y: 115,
            width: 330
        }, {
            x: 20,
            y: 125,
            width: 330
        }],
```

You'll need to do that for both the `textPointsNoImage` and `textPoints` arrays.

Or as an alternative, `.push()` additional text point objects into the arrays in the theme you are using.